# filter elements of an array and display them using the same array

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have a state in pinia which is an array of objects that I add elements to by doing a fetch, in a component I get this array and run through it using v-for and show some cards, in the parent component where I run the array I have some buttons to filter elements of the array by a type, for this in the state I create another array where the filtered elements are going to go and in the component I verify that if it is empty, add the elements of the original array. I created a function that I command to call on each button passing it the type that is what I am going to filter by, and here I just go through the array of filtered elements using filter, and check with the type if it is the same as what I am passing to the function add it to the filters array. For this I pass in the v-for the new array of filters to show them for each button, but since I can do this without using another array, I want to use the original array because I do a search from an input and I do it to the original array, Is this possible to do? I think that using a computer could be done but I can't find the way.

state:

```js
export const useObjStore = defineStore('ObjStore', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      array: [],
      filtersArray: []
    }
  },
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    fetchElements() {
      // .....
    }
  }
})
```

component:

```html
<button
  class="d-flex align-items-center button-option cursor-pointer px-2"
  @click="filterByType('uno')"
>Uno</button>

<button
  class="d-flex align-items-center button-option cursor-pointer px-2"
  @click="filterByType('two')"
>Two</button>

<button
  class="d-flex align-items-center button-option cursor-pointer px-2"
  @click="filterByType('three')"
>Three</button>
```

component where I loop through the array:

```html
<card
  v-for="(elem, n) in filtersArray"
  :key="`elem-${n}`"
  :elem="elem"
  class="mb-4"
/>
```

```js
if (filtersArray.value.length === 0) {
  filtersArray.value = array
}

const filterByType = (type) => {
  filtersArray = array.filter((val) => val.type === type)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage a `filterBy` state in your pinia store which will track the type of filter that have been applied. Then, you can have a computed value with getters like this:

```
getters: {
    filteredArray: (state) => state.filterBy ? state.array.filter((val) => val.type === state.filterBy) : state.array;
}
```